# MATLAB semi supervised classifier

Tags: matlab, classification

I have a set of 132 elements that are described by 5 features. I have the labels for these elements

```
features= rand(132,5);
labels= [ones(132,1);2*ones(132,1)];
```

For my classification problem I found that if I transform the features in the following way:

```
B=pdist(features);
C = squareform(B);
[V,D] = eig(C);
```

and then take as new features the eigenvectors in `V`

```
new_features = V;
```

I get good accuracy.

In particular I train a supervised classifier using the new_features and test it in a 10 fold cross validation.

The problem is that I do not know the transformation from `feature` to `new_features` for an unknown new element `new_element = rand(1,5)`.

I was thinking then to train a semi-supervised classifier (without the label of the new unknown element, but using it for the transformation) and then test the performance on the unknown (unlabelled) elements.

Could you recommend a MATLAB implementation of a semi-supervised classifier or a way to transform the unknown new element in the eigenvector space of the known elements (used for a training of the supervised classifier)?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Adriaan I modified my question